# Invalid Python SDK

Tags: python, python-3.8

It have problems with my interpreter it says:

`Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/python3.8" (in directory "/usr/local/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory Pls`

How can I fix this

Comment: At first sight, you don't have python3.! on your machine at that path. You could try with `which python3.8`

Comment: If you are using windows, add python to environment path.

Comment: I'm using a mac